# Exterior metal threshold to transition from concrete to tiled entryway?

Tags: tile, threshold

Is it possible to transition from the sidewalk concrete to my tiled entryway by using an aluminum exterior grade threshold? I am thinking of something along the lines of this:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/M-D-Building-Products-Flat-Top-2-1-2-in-x-48-in-Aluminum-Saddle-Threshold-99028048000/205967458

I just had my tiler guys finish the job and I can't believe they installed a tile with a chip in it. But it's along the edge and it kinda also looks unfinished anyway I thought a simple aluminum exterior grade threshold would make it look more finished and hide the small chip. Here are a couple of images:

[image]

[image]

I live in the desert so and this area is covered by an eve and only gets about three hours sun a day and approximately a mere four inches of rain a year. Will my idea weather well or can anyone recommend something else?

Comment: Frankly I'd complain to your tile guys about the chipped tile, and mortar in a stone threshold (typically marble or granite, available in a few widths) or bullnose tiles for a finished edge.

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant issue with aluminum **in** concrete - e.g., an aluminum post or conduit embedded in concrete is not a good idea. My hunch is that a piece of aluminum on top of already cured concrete will not have the same issues. However, I am not a metallurgist and so, to play it safe, I would look for a similar piece of steel instead.

On the other hand, a quick search finds steel thresholds to be a bit on the expensive side. I suggest checking with an aluminum threshold manufacturer to see if installation **on top of** concrete is acceptable.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm left wondering that if it's on top of concrete that it'll be fine. Most exterior prehung doors that have an aluminum threshold at the bottom sit on top of concrete and seem to do fine.